# How to build JSON array with custom columns in postgres

Tags: jquery, json, postgresql

I am trying to extract data from table in JSON format using postgres.
In table i have columns lets say: water = 1, airport = 2,
What i need is to add additional columns to final json object which should look like this:

```
"[
{"type": "water", "value": 1},
{"type": "airport", "value": 2},
]"
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(
     json_build_object('type', 'water', 'value', water)
 ))
 FROM  table;
```

but I am able to produce just an object for water...
output looks like this:

```
"[{"type" : "port", "value" : 1}]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your `table` structure and contents for at least water and airport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somethings like this based on your code.

```
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg( json_build_object('type', 'water', 'value', water))::jsonb ||
    jsonb_agg( json_build_object('type', 'water', 'value', airport) )::jsonb,
    jsonb_agg( json_build_object('type', 'water', 'value', water))::jsonb,
    jsonb_agg( json_build_object('type', 'water', 'value', airport)))
    AS data
FROM   table;
```

Comment: Maybe you can add to your answer how to skip object if lets say water is null?

Comment: Also would be nice to know how to add same objects but from LEFT JOIN table which can have multiple values which should produce multiple json_build_object within same level as water

Comment: @VytautasPranskunas updated with coalesce.

Comment: Yes, thanks i have already solved with COALESCE
Now the problem is with left join because when i have this  SELECT 
  COALESCE(json_agg(country.codes)), '[]')::jsonb ||
  json_agg(json_build_object('name', 'port', 'value', port))::jsonb
 as data
FROM token as tt
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('name', 'country', 'value', tc.iso)) AS codes
   FROM   token_country as tc
   WHERE  tc.token_id = tt.id
   ) country ON true
WHERE tt.id = 1
I have countries wrapped into additional array [[{name...}], {water:..}] can you help woth that @Mark?

Comment: p.s. your example with COALESCE is not correct because json_builder_object will never be null - since it is always producing at least {'type': 'water', 'value': null)

Comment: regarding COALESCE should be liek this: COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object( 'name', 'port', 'value', port)
        ) FILTER (WHERE port IS NOT NULL), '[]')::jsonb